# 「Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？」のアイコンが実際と異なる

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ

[Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

の「コードスニペット」と「画像」の

> ツールバーにあるスニペット用のアイコン [image: コードスニペット用のツールバーアイコン] をクリックするか、<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> を押してください。

> 画像はエディタのツールバーにあるボタン[image: 画像挿入用のツールバーアイコン]から挿入します。

のアイコンやボタンの画像が実際のアイコン(下記の左から14番目と6番目)とは異なります。

[image: エディターのアイコン群]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

以下の古い画像から、

[image]
[image]

以下の新しい画像に差し替えました。

[image]
[image]